# How do I make applescript perform an operation ONLY on a specified application?

Tags: applescript, google-chrome

I am trying to make something that types a word automatically on Google Chrome. However, when I run my code, it types the specified word on any open application with an available textbox. How do I make it so that my code runs ONLY on google chrome and so that I don't have to keep the chrome window open all the time. Here's what I have so far:

```
tell application "System Events"
 set texttosay to "apple"
 repeat
   activate application "Google Chrome"
   delay 2
   repeat 100000000 times
        keystroke texttosay
        keystroke return
        delay 40
   end repeat
 end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: GUI scripting only applies to the currently active application - that is the way it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following script does what you want: basically checks if Chrome is open belore launching your script.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
if it is running then
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        set texttosay to "apple"
        repeat
            delay 2
            repeat 100000000 times
                keystroke texttosay
                keystroke return
                delay 2
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end if
end tell
```

My inspiration:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107418/open-url-and-activate-google-chrome-via-applescript

Comment: Once in that repeat loop, changing the active application will still result in System Events sending the keystrokes to whatever it is.

Comment: yes exactly. Place the repeat outside of the `tell` or not is a matter of taste. I don't know @mine exact situation, but I hope this piece of code can be rearranged as he/she wishes.